# Is there a way to set the visibility of a button of the actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have two activities.ActivityA and AcitivityB. I have 4 buttons in my actionbar, but in ActivityA only three should be visible, if I press a certain button, I get into ActivityB and there all four should be visible.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can set the visibility through setVisibility on the MenuItem instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just inflate a separate menu resource in each activities onCreateOptionsMenu?

```
class ActivityA extends Activity {
    /**Code omitted*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activityA, menu);
        return true;
    }
}

class ActivityB extends Activity {
    /**Code omitted*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activityB, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes I advice you to create special class ActionBarHelper where you incapsulate all ActionBar initialisation steps.In my app which uses ActionbarSherlock i did this in ActionBarHelper class code:

```
public static void initActionBar(final SherlockActivity activity, final boolean finishCurrent) {
    activity.setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light);
    theBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    theBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    theBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_bar);
             // other initialisation
```

And then

```
Button btnToHide = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btnToHide);
    if (activity.getLocalClassName().toString().equals("ActivityA")) {
        btnToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }`
```

And in you activities `OnCreate()` just write `ActionBarHelper.initActionBar(this,false);`

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of the corresponding activity you can call the setVisibility to the desired button to hide it.